# Failing to assign value to variable in a defined function

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, function, replace

I am attempting to define a function that strips whitespace and hyphens from a string, for instance it would edit `foo - bar` to `foobar`.

The original string should be stored under a named variable (e.g. `orig_str`) and the amended string returned under a new variable name (e.g. `amended_str`).

My attempt to define such a function fails to do anything at all.

```
#This is what my function looks like

def normalise_str(old_string, new_string):          #def func
    temp_string = old_string.replace(" ", "")       #rm whitespace
    temp_string = temp_string.replace("-", "")      #rm hyphens
    new_string = temp_string                        #assign newly modified str to var

#This is what I would like to achieve

orig_str = "foo - bar"
normalise_str = (orig_str, amended_str)
print(amended_str) #I would like this to return "foobar"
```

I would definitely value a more efficient solution along the lines of...

```
amended_str = orig_str.replace(" " and "-", "") #I'm sure something sensible like this exists
```

However I need to understand what I am doing wrong with my function in order to advance my learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current version fails because strings cannot be modified after creation (see note); instead do the following:

```py
amended_str = normalize_str(orig_str)
```

The shortened version of what you want is:

```py
def normalize_str(in_str):
    return in_str.replace(' ', '').replace('-', '')

# Or
normalize_str = lambda s: s.replace(' ', '').replace('-', '')
```

*Note: You cannot modify the string passed as an argument because strings are immutable - meaning once created, they **cannot** be modified.*

Answer (score 1):

You need to input the old string, make your changes, then return the final temp string back to the variable.

```
#This is what my function looks like

def normalise_str(old_string):          #def func
    temp_string = old_string.replace(" ", "")       #rm whitespace
    temp_string = temp_string.replace("-", "")      #rm hyphens
    return temp_string                     #assign newly modified str to var

#This is what I would like to achieve

orig_str = "foo - bar"
s = normalise_str(orig_str)
print(s) #I would like this to return "foobar"
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are non-mutable objects, which means in Python that the original string outside the function cannot be modified. Therefore, you need to explicitly return the modified string.

```
def normalise_str(old_string):          
    return old_str.replace(' ','').replace('-', '')

orig_str = "foo - bar"
amended_str = normalise_str(old_string)
print(amended_str) # Should print foobar
```

Comment: OP wanted to replace inner-spaces as well (I had the same thing at first, haha)